# Replace call to System.currentTimeMillis() at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

I am using a JAR file that uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current system time. I want to call my current time method (`nanoTime()`) when a function of JAR file calls `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Any suggestion how I can cover this?

Comment: Without the source, easiest is to decompile the relevant class, change the call and then rebuild the jar.

Comment: JAR file is encrypted and not possible to decompile and then rebuild that.

Comment: Of course it's possible, otherwise the JVM would not be able to load it. What is not possible is to dynamically change the calls a class is making at runtime. If you can't change the JAR, you can't change what the classes call.

Comment: Are you asking something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749409/replace-content-of-some-methods-at-runtime)?

Comment: Not exactly. One way to replace call to time method is to replace all methods that uses that. I know how to do that using Javassit. However, the problem is then I need to override more than 100 methods. So, not good idea. On the other hand, I am not sure if it is possible to override System.currentTimeMillis() method with Javassit. Let me know if possible?

Comment: You do understand that these methods return completely different values, both in units and in origin/zero?

Comment: Yes. I know, and that is the reason I want to use nanoTime.

Comment: I do not see the problem with javassist? Yes this will modify the bytecode of each class calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` (replacing this call) but the framework does it for you. And you can limit the replacements to the classes you want. Besides: Why do you expect that changing currentTimeMillis to nanoTime does not break the modified code?

Answer (score 1):

Well... implementing you own `java.lang.System` comes into mind. But then you'd also need set your bootclasspath and who knows what else to make this work. You might end up patching `rt.jar`.

It will be tricky though to reuse the "real" `System` class for all other purposes.

And I hope you plan to do this on one machine only - I can't imagine the trouble to deploy such a system.