# Able to alter code of libraries imported with Gradle (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, import, android-studio, gradle

Is it possible to alter the code of a library imported through `Gradle` in `Android Studio`? I am thinking it isn't possible since the libraries get added in at runtime?

Is there anything equivalent of `extensions in Swift` in `Java`? An extension in `Swift` is basically a way to add more functions/methods to an existing class. Without directly altering the original source code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Is it possible to alter the code of a library imported through Gradle in Android Studio?" -- not really. "Is there anything equivalent of extensions in Swift in Java?" -- since few people monitoring the `android` tag are going to be familiar with Swift, you may wish to explain what you mean.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381226/is-it-possible-to-monkey-patch-in-java This seems to be only possible for Java bytecode. For Dex bytecode which is used in Android at runtime, I don't think that approach would work unless someone wrote a tool for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to alter the code of a library imported through Gradle in Android Studio?

Not as you are defining it, per your Swift extension reference.

> An extension in Swift is basically a way to add more functions/methods to an existing class. Without directly altering the original source code.

Java does not have this, sorry.